# cannot display JSON data from the backend in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

Am getting data from the back end(api) but i cannot display it to the view.
i have tried several solutions but diddn't seem to work.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data">
     <h4>{{item.address}}</h4>
     <h4>{{item.city}}</h4>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the data is pasted below. I used JSON.stringify() to convert the data from object to string and stored it in a variable getEventData. when i do interpolation of the results like this `{{getEventData}}` it comes alright but cannot format it.
thanks in advance.

```
//get request to api
        this._http.get( this.url + param, {headers:headers})
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => this.getEventData = JSON.stringify(data),
                error =>this.logError(error),
                () => console.log('get request completed sucesfully')
            );
```

data from api

```
 {
    "data": [
        {
            "address": "Great 22", 
            "banner_image": null, 
            "city": "Kum", 
            "country": "", 
            "creator_id": 15, 
            "description": "50th congregation", 
            "end_time": "2016-07-05T15:30:00+00:00", 
            "event_id": 5, 
            "is_online": false, 
            "max_tickets_per_user": 1, 
            "show_id": 7, 
            "start_time": "2016-07-05T09:00:00+00:00", 
            "state": "Ash", 
            "title": "Graduation", 
            "venue": "Great Hall"
        }, 
        {
            "address": "CCB Auditorium", 
            "banner_image": null, 
            "city": "Kumasi", 
            "country": "hema", 
            "creator_id": 15, 
            "description": "school graduation", 
            "end_time": "2016-07-06T15:30:00+00:00", 
            "event_id": 5, 
            "is_online": false, 
            "max_tickets_per_user": 1, 
            "show_id": 8, 
            "start_time": "2016-07-06T09:00:00+00:00", 
            "state": "hama", 
            "title": "Graduation", 
            "venue": "CCB Auditorium"
        }, 
        {
            "address": "Engineering Auditorium", 
            "banner_image": null, 
            "city": "Kumasi", 
            "country": "Ghana", 
            "creator_id": 15, 
            "description": "KNUST graduation for the 50th congregation", 
            "end_time": "2016-07-06T15:30:00+00:00", 
            "event_id": 5, 
            "is_online": false, 
            "max_tickets_per_user": 1, 
            "show_id": 9, 
            "start_time": "2016-07-06T09:00:00+00:00", 
            "state": "Ash", 
            "title": "Graduation", 
            "venue": "Engineering Auditorium"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think it should work. is this what your `getEventData` contains?

Comment: do `{{data|json}}` and copy and paste value in your question.

Comment: yes @ micronyks. by interpolation i get the above json data

Comment: reproduce problem in plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `JSON.stringify` if you plan to render data with `*ngFor`:

```
.subscribe(
    data => this.getEventData = data.data, // note extra .data
    error => this.logError(error),
    () => console.log('get request completed succesfully')
);
```

Comment: `{{getEventData}}` produces  `[object Object],[object Object]`. also by logging getEventData to the console the output is like this: `Array(2)` @dfsq

Comment: thanks it works for me. 1. I took away the key `"data"` from the result set. i fixed that from the backend.                                                                       2. So i did `*ngFor="let item of getEventData"` instead.  3. and                  4. did `data => this.getEventData = data.data`